# UIImage gets clipped when using UiTapGesturerecognizer

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using the code below to display my image in full screen when a user taps on the image. This image is inside a tableview.

```
func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let imageView = self.moreImageView
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView?.image)
    newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    //newImageView.sizeToFit()
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.addSubview(newImageView)

}
```

But when I tap the screen the image renders full screen, but the upper and lower parts of the image always gets clipped. How do I make sure the image resizes and fits in correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want `.scaleAspectFit`

Fit will make it fit inside the space (and show the background color on parts that don't fill)

Comment: That still clips the lower half of the image.

Comment: What is UIScreen.main.bounds and self.bounds (the superview to the imageView)?

Comment: So the image view sits in a cell in a tableview and its constraints are set to 0 on the left and right, and single digit numbers for top and bottom. Not sure if that helps, sorry, doing this for the first time. Would setting an aspect ration for the image help ?

Comment: images have a height and width, so therefore they have an aspect ratio already. Probably show a little more code and perhaps some screen shots to explain what you have and what you want.